# How to sort names by surname

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

I would like to sort the below list of full names by their surname (a-z). How could we do that with a sorted function and a lambda? Is there a better way?

```
people = ['Fred Johnson', 'Tom E. Roth', 'Jazz Ishingham', 'Fred Kazai', 'Robert Wass', 'You  Mee']
```

Comment: Required reading on the topic of parsing names: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to supplement the other answers: in the case when 'people' list elements can have trailing spaces, we can remove them this way:

```py
sorted(people, key=lambda el: el.rstrip().split(' ')[-1])
```

Also we could use `re` module this way:

```py
import re
sorter = lambda el: re.search(r'(\w+)(?:\s*)$', el).group(1)
sorted(people, key=sorter)
```

Here we take only a surname, without any trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://chrisalbon.com/python/basics/sort_a_list_by_last_name/

The answer is to your problem is `sorted(people, key=lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1]`

Comment: What about Mr. "Tom E. Roth"? There are two spaces there?